# ros-jade-desktop-full not setting up ros or gazebo setup files properly

Tags: gazebo, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Normally, after an install of ros-jade-desktop-full on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (trusty) 64-bit, the gazebo 5.0 package is setup to run properly.

I tried to set up a new computer this afternoon, and it is giving me an error because there is no /usr/share/gazebo library.

I know this was working a couple of weeks ago.  Has there been a change to debs that busted this?

Attached is screen shot of result:
[image: image description]

This after apt-get removing prior attempts, apt-get updating/upgrading, and rebooting.  I started install of ros-jade-desktop-full, and redirected to file.  The install seems to complete without error, but I have no /usr/share/gazebo folder and no setup files in the /opt/ros/jade folder

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226387/ros-jade-desktop-full-not-setting-up-ros-or--gazebo-setup-files-properly/) by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-12**:
Could you edit your post to include the full error that you are seeing?

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2016-02-12**:
Normally, the install creates a /usr/share/gazebo-5.0 folder with models and code, and a /usr/share/gazebo  folder with setup script that points to the appropriate version of gazebo.

You need to source this to run gazebo stand alone.  This folder is not being created.

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2016-02-12**:
This morning I removed (sudo apt-get remove ) ros-jade-desktop-full, and tried to re-install.
Now the setup script in /opt/ros/jade is missing.

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2016-02-12**:
In my prior (last couple of weeks) installs of ros-jade-desktop-full, it installed gazebo-5.1.  Now I notice that it installed 5.0 this morning.

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2016-02-12**:
I filed a ticket https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/10490 in case this is some widespread issue.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-12**:
I'm a bit confused: is the issue with Gazebo or with ROS? Your question title suggests Gazebo isn't being installed correctly, but your comments suggest you are encountering some issues with ROS itself. For the former, I'd suggest reporting to the Gazebo people, the latter we can deal with here.

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2016-02-12**:
As posted on the rosdistro ticket.  This started as an issue with the Gazebo5 package embedded in the ROS jade desktop full.  After removing and trying a fresh install of ROS this morning, I have an issue with both Gazebo and /opt/ros/jade setup files missing.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-02-12**:
What does `dpkg -l | grep ros-jade-catkin` output?

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2016-02-12**:
Between my post of the screen shot, and seeing Dirk's comment, I did a apt-get clean to remove all prior packages.  I had not done the after my prior apt-get remove / autoremoves.

After doing that, I was able to install ros and get the setup files.
At this point,  I have

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2016-02-12**:
ii  ros-jade-catkin                                       0.6.16-0trusty-20160110-082557-0800                 amd64        Low-level build system macros and infrastructure for ROS.

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2016-02-12**:
I still have Gazebo-5.0 installed, when I thought Gazebo 5.1 was the default for Jade, and there was no /usr/share/gazebo folder as I expected based on prior installs
That was the source of my original question.

I get gazebo-3.0 and gazebo-5.0 directories installed with ros-jade-desktop-full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was installing ROS Jade in this morning too...

When I installed the distribution, I tried to run `gazebo` command and it was launched successfully. But, I got an error when I stopped to run Gazebo. I figured out that I didnt set up smth, so I followed to [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing&cat=connect_ros)  and Gazebo works fine now.

---

Originally posted by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) with karma: 200 on 2016-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2016-02-12**:
Are you saying you installed ros, and then manually installed gazebo?
Which version?  Jade normally uses Gazebo5, but those instructions are for gazebo7.

I tried reinstalling jade this morning, and not the setup script that is supposed to be in /opt/ros/jade  is missing.

**Comment by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on 2016-02-13**:
Gazebo 5.1.0. I installed first ros and the folders `gazebo_msgs`, `gazebo_plugins`, `gazebo_ros`, `gazebo_ros_pkgs` appeared in /opt/ros/jade/share. I ran Gazebo after and it opened successfully. But, I decided to visit [gazebo tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_overview) and I foun

**Comment by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on 2016-02-13**:
... I found that gazebo_ros_pkgs should be in catkin_ws.